# Generating 3D points from Disparity

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Can someone point out the math involved in getting the 3d points of an image from its disparity values?I have the Image(i,j) and disparity at each of these points.What i want is the true 3D coordinate x,y,z using math equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer - [http://www.amazon.com/Multiple-View-Geometry-Computer-Vision/dp/0521540518/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518)

Short answer.
You have the pixel scale, so for a given number of pixel disparity you can get an angle different. With the baseline between cameras and an angle you have a distance

ps. take a look at the opencv book, it has a couple of good chapters on stereo
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a more mathemetical version of this or direct me to one?

Comment: chapter12 of the opencv - you can probably preview it on google. Or the whole of the Hartley book.